# registerForContexMenu on two different lists

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I hava 2 listvies on the same activity list1 and list2.
I want to have A,B,C items when press and hold on list1, and P,O,I on list2

how can this be done ? 
Should I call
registerforcontextmenu(list1); and registerforcontextmenu(list2); ?? 
and what afterwards . . .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want different contextMenu for different Listview then try this

then create context Menu

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
if(v==list1)
{ 
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "A");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "B");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "C");
}
else if(v==list2)
{ 
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 3, Menu.NONE, "P");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 4, Menu.NONE, "Q");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 5, Menu.NONE, "R");
}        

}
```

and register conextMenu on both listview.

```
registerForContextMenu(list1);
registerForContextMenu(list2);
```

Comment: you mean on lognpress ?, cause onClick listener would not work

Comment: Cool you compare the View :), that is the exact thing I needed :), tnx